# How to post impact ASP MVC code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

A couple of days ago I was talking to a senior senior developer about post impact debugging. He mentioned that there are ways to get ASP MVC websites on a bug to log down the whole stacktrace, store the data state, a rendered screenshot image of the website, put everything into a a zip file and dump it onto the disk.

I was a bit surprised and did not ask him how to do this. It sounds a bit far fetched to me (the screenshot part especially) so I started googling and could not find anything.

Is anyone aware of something like this available through IIS, ASP MVC or any 3rd party libs.